# How to redirect a wordpress user after logon?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

Here is the original code from my WP Theme. It redirects a logged on user to the home page.

```
static function redirect_field() {
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] ) ) {
        $redirect = $_REQUEST['redirect_to'];
    } else {
        $redirect = home_url();
    }
```

What I want to do is redirect the user to a specific page on the site (Page Post). This is what I changed the redirect variable to:

```
static function redirect_field() {
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] ) ) {
        $redirect = $_REQUEST['redirect_to'];
    } else {
        $redirect = get_page_by_path('/volume-rates');

    }
```

This did not work for me. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to the functions.php file will redirect a user after logging in.

```
add_action('login_form', 'redirect_after_login'); 
function redirect_after_login() 
{     
    global $redirect_to; 
    if   (!isset($_GET['redirect_to'])) 
    { 
        $redirect_to =   '/volume-rates';
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this, it didn't work, because the theme is already using it's own redirect to its own customized logon page. So here is what I did: I used my code above and changed this one line. '$redirect = site_url('/volume-rates');'